# Awk: Append output to new field in existing file

Tags: awk, printing, append, field

Is there a way to print the output of an awk script to an existing file as a new field every time?

Hi!
I'm very new at awk (so my terminology might not be correct, sorry about that!) and I'm trying to print the output of a script that will operate on several hundred files to the same file, in different fields.

For example, my data files have this structure:

```
#File1
1
Values, 2, Hanna
20
15
Values, 2, Josh
30 
56
Values, 2, Anna
50
70

#File2
2
Values, 2, Hanna
45
60
Values, 2, Josh
98 
63
Values, 2, Anna
10
56
```

I have several of these files, which are divided by numbered month, with the same names, but different values. I want files that are named by the name of the person, and the values in fields by month, like so:

```
#Hanna
20 45
15 60

#Josh
30 98
56 63

#Anna
50 10
70 56
```

In my script, I search for the word "values", and determine which records to print (based on the number after "value"). This works fine. Then I want to print these values. It works fine for one file, with the command:

`Print $0 > name` #the varible name have I saved to be = $3 of the correct row

This creates three files correctly named "Hanna", "Josh" and "Anna", with their values. However, I would like to run the script for all my datafiles, and append them to only one "Hanna"-file etc, in a new field.

So what I'm looking for is something like `print $0 > $month name`, reading out like "print the record to the field corresponding to the month"

I have tried to find a solution, but most solutions either just paste temporary files together or append the values after the existing ones (so that they all are in field 1). I want to avoid the temporary files and have them in different fields (so that I get a kind of matrix-structure).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following, though I have not checked all permutations and combinations and only considered your post. Also your output Josh column is not consistent also(Or please do let us know if more conditions are there for same too). Let me know how it goes then.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if($0 ~ /^Values/){Q=$NF;B[$NF]=$NF;i="";next};A[Q,++i]=$0;next} /^Values/{V=$NF;print "#"B[V];i="";next} B[V]{print A[V,++i],$0}' file1 file2
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
                if($0 ~ /^Values/){
                                        Q=$NF;
                                        B[$NF]=$NF;
                                        i="";
                                        next
                                  };
                A[Q,++i]=$0;
                next
            }
     /^Values/{
                V=$NF;
                print "#"B[V];
                i="";
                next
              }
     B[V]{
                print A[V,++i],$0
         }
    ' file1 file2
```

**EDIT2:** Adding explanation too now for same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{                                      ###Checking condition FNR==NR where this condition will be TRUE only when first file named file1 is being read. FNR and NR both indicate number of lines in a Input_file, only difference between them is FNR value will be RESET whenever there is next Input_file is being read and NR value will be keep on incresing till all the Input_files are read.
                if($0 ~ /^Values/){                ###Checking here if any line starts from string Values if yes then perform following operations.
                                        Q=$NF;     ###Creating a variable named Q whose value is the last field of the line.
                                        B[$NF]=$NF;###Creating an array named B whose index is $NF(last field of the line) and value is same too.
                                        i="";      ###Making variable i value to NULL now.
                                        next       ###using next here, it is built-in keyword for awk and it will skip all further statements now.
                                  };
                A[Q,++i]=$0;                       ###Creating an array named A whose index is Q and variable i with increasing value with 1 to it, each time it comes on this statement.
                next                               ###Using next will skip all further statements now.
            }
     /^Values/{                                    ###All statements from here will be executed when second file named file2 is being read. So I am checking here if a line starts from string Values then do following.
                V=$NF;                             ###create variable V whose value is $NF of current line.
                print "#"B[V];                     ###printing the string # then value of array B whose index is variable V.
                i="";                              ###Nullifying the variable i value here.
                next                               ###next will sip all the further statements now.
              }
     B[V]{                                         ###Checking here if array B with index V is having a value in it, then perform following on it too.
                print A[V,++i],$0                  ###printing the value of array A whose index is variable V and variable i increasing value with 1 and current line.
         }
    ' file1 file2                                  ###Mentioning the Input_files here named file1 and file2.
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I corrected the Josh-typo above.
However, as I am very new to awk I don't really understand how to implement you solution? I'm writing it in a txt-file with the syntax BEGIN{....}, and running it by writing awk -f script.txt data1.data from the terminal. Should I write your code inside my txt-file or in the terminal? Sorry for not knowing more, I thought this might be solved by a simple combination of '>' and '$' :P Sorry for putting you through so much trouble.

Comment: Cool, I added explanation also now for this one, keep learning, sharing :) EDIT: You could run it on terminal also, you could create a BASH script and run from that also and yes you could run it from awk -f also by doing little changes in it, let me know how it goes for you

Comment: Wow, so this (kind of) works! (and made the rest of my code redundant haha). Thanks so much! However, and I see now that this was a bit unclear. I would like the ouputs to be saved to three different files, according to the names. So the file titled "Anna" should contain Anna's four numbers, a file "Josh" with Josh's numbers etc. Where could I implement this? In my original code I just had [> name] at the end of the sequence, but now it saves all the values to Anna.

Comment: I solved it, now I have three seperate files! (added "> B[V]" to the last line. Thank you so so much! :D